# How to group mat-radio-button row wise in angular material tabel

Tags: html, angular5, angular2-forms, angular-material-5

[image]

Normally angular material table groups radio buttons column wise, How can I achieve row wise grouping?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-groups) on radio groups it states that

> Radio-buttons should typically be placed inside of an
>   `<mat-radio-group>` **unless the DOM structure would make that
>   impossible (e.g., radio-buttons inside of table cells)**.

So if you want to have a radio button group per row, then you would just use the name property to group these controls together (exactly how you would for an HTML input type="radio").

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <p>Escalation Teams</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <mat-radio-button value="1" name="escalationTeam"></mat-radio-button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <mat-radio-button value="2" name="escalationTeam"></mat-radio-button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[See my Stackblitz example](https://angular-jnnsay.stackblitz.io) as shown below:

[image: radios grouped by row]

Notice how for each row you can only check one radio at a time

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want a column of radio buttons in a single table cell, or multiple rows each with a single radio button in the same column (this doesn't seem likely)? The image shows radio buttons in separate data columns in the same row. You can't have multiple data columns appear in a single view column and and row, so you would need a single data column contain the selected option, and the view for that cell to lay out the various radio options in a vertical format. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4tbgm) example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I think I can make use of it, just need to club columns.
My requirement was to be able to click only one radio button in a row.. which is not happening in the picture which I have posted.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, it won't be possible to have radio buttons in separate *data* columns belong to the same radio group, so you would have to fake that with layout in a single column. My example shows column layout - change it to row and remove the radio button labels, then also modify the column header to provide the label for each radio button.